# PING error through enc0: Frag needed and DF set (mtu = 0)

Tags: openbsd, ping, nat, ipsec

I'm up ipsec vpn client to remote host. Since the remote host accepts only one ip i'm up nat for local net on enc0. Ping from ipsec host is ok:

```
PING 172.20.162.150 (172.20.162.150): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.20.162.150: icmp_seq=0 ttl=252 time=2.597 ms
```

But ping from local net is fail:

```
PING 172.20.162.150 (172.20.162.150) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.5 icmp_seq=1 Frag needed and DF set (mtu = 0)
```

MTU for enc0 = 0 and I can not change it

```
netstat -i
Name    Mtu   Network     Address              Ipkts Ierrs    Opkts Oerrs Colls
enc0    0     <Link>                              29     0       29     0     0
enc0    0     172.25.41.1 172.25.41.10            29     0       29     0     0
```

I've tried use scrub in pf.conf but it did not help:

```
match in on enc0 scrub (no-df max-mss 1300) 
or match in all scrub (no-df max-mss 1300)
```

sudo ifconfig enc0 mtu 1452 return:

```
SIOCSIFMTU: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Unfortunately, there is no solution options (((

Other settings that may help to understand:

```
172.20.162.150 - remote host
172.25.41.10 - local ip for enc0 (only this ip accepted by 172.20.162.150)
192.168.1.0/24 local net and 192.168.1.5 ip of my host for local net

/etc/hostname.enc0
inet 172.25.41.10 255.255.255.255
up
!/sbin/route add -host 172.20.162.150 172.25.41.10

/etc/ipsec.conf
ike esp from 172.25.41.10/32 to 172.20.162.150/32 peer 80.*.*.132 \
    main auth hmac-sha1 enc aes-256 group modp1024 lifetime 86400 \
    quick auth hmac-sha1 enc aes-256 group modp1024 lifetime 3600 \
    psk ***********

/etc/pf.conf
pass from 172.20.162.150 to any
pass out quick on enc0 from <localnet> to 172.20.162.150 nat-to enc0 keep state (if-bound)

tcpdump for ping from local net for internal net if
192.168.1.13 > 172.20.162.150: icmp: echo request (id:777a seq:5) [icmp cksum ok] (DF) (ttl 64, id 30758, len 84)
192.168.1.5 > 192.168.1.13: icmp: 172.20.162.150 unreachable - need to frag [icmp cksum ok] (ttl 255, id 44410, len 56, bad ip cksum 0! -> 8ae7)

tcpdump for enc0 is empty.

Statistic for nat from pfctl:
sudo pfctl -s state | grep 172.20.162.150
all icmp 172.20.162.150:8 <- 192.168.1.13:30586       0:0
enc0 icmp 172.25.41.10:61751 (192.168.1.13:30586) -> 172.20.162.150:8       0:0
```

Can someone faced with similar, prompt solution to the problem.

Comment: Do you control the VPN server? What is it?

Comment: No(. I only know that this Cisco ASA, do not even know the model.